# Code won't run once adding transactions

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, transactions

Hello I have code that without transactions executes but with transactions doesn't run. My `DB Class` encapsulates prepared statements from which it is composed in my `BaseApp Class` and this is in turn is  extended by `BaseTransactApp Class`.

`BasetransactApp Class`  is extended by the `EqRqst Class`. `EqRqst Class` is extended by the `EqLeaseRequest Class` which is used to call the code in the trait with the problematic code.
At one point it showed the error `2SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error`
when I did not set

```
$this->_pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES , false);
```

My `DB Class` is

```
 <?php
        class DB{
   `enter code here` private static $_instance = null;
    private $_pdo,
            $_query,
            $_error = false,
            $_results,
            $x,
            $_count = 0;


      private function __construct(){
        try{
               $this->_pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' .Config::get('mysql/host') . ';dbname=' . Config::get('mysql/db'), Config::get('mysql/username'),       Config::get('mysql/password'));
            $this->_pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $this->_pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES , false);
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            die($e->getMessage());
        }

        } 
        public static function getInstance(){
            if(!isset(self::$_instance)){
                self::$_instance = new DB();
            }
            return self::$_instance;
        }
        public function query($sql, $params = array()){
            $this->_error = false;
            if($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)){
                $x = 1;
               if(count($params)){
                foreach($params as $param){
                    $this->_query->bindValue($x,$param);
                    $x++;
                }
               }
               if($this->_query->execute()){
              $this->_results = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
              $this->_count = $this->_query->rowCount();


               }else{
                $this->_error = true;
               } 
            }
     return $this;

        }
        public function action($action,$table,$where = array()){
            if(count($where) === 3){
  $operators = array('=','>','<','>=','<=');

         $field = $where[0];
         $operator = $where[1];
         $value = $where[2];

         if(in_array($operator , $operators)){
            $sql = "{$action} FROM {$table} WHERE {$field} {$operator} ? ";
            if(!$this->query($sql, array($value))->error()){
                return $this;
            }

         }

            }
            return false;
        }
        public function update($table,$id,$fields){
            $set = '';
            $x = 1;
            foreach($fields as $name => $value){
                $set .= "{$name} = ?";
                if($x < count($fields)){
                    $set .= ', ';
                }
                $x++;
            }

            $sql = "UPDATE {$table} SET {$set} WHERE {$name} = '{$id}'";
            echo $sql;
            if(!$this->query($sql,$fields)->error()){
                echo "true";

                return true;

            }
           return false;
        }


        public function get($table,$where){
        return $this->action('SELECT *',$table,$where);
        }
        public function delete($table,$where){
            return $this->action('DELETE',$table,$where);
        }
        public function insert($table,$fields = array()){
            if(count($fields)){
                echo 'this is the count  '.count($fields);
                $x=1;
               if(!is_multi_array($fields)){
                echo 'Not a multi array'.'<br>';
                $keys = array_keys($fields);
                print_r($keys);
                $values = '';



                }
                foreach($fields as $field => $fieldValue){
                    if(!is_array($fieldValue)){

                        echo $x;
                         $values .="?";
                   if($x< count($fields)){
                    $values .= ', ';
                   }
                   if($x == count($fields)){
                    echo 'insert query is Executed'.'<br>';
                    echo $x;
                     $sql ="INSERT INTO {$table} (`".implode('`,`',$keys). "`) VALUES ({$values})";
                       if(!$this->query($sql,$fields)->error()){ 
                echo "true";
                return true;
              }


                   }
                   $x++;
                    }else{
                        if($x <= count($fields)){
                         echo 'recursive insert called'.'<br>';
                         echo "number of recursive cycles is    ".$x;
                          $this->insert($table,$fieldValue);
                          if($x == count($fields)){
                            echo "Escaped";
                            exit();
                          }
                          $x++;
                        }



                     }
                   }




            }

           echo 'No no'; 
         return false;
        }

            public function getLastId(){
               return $this->_pdo->lastInsertId();
            }
            public function beginTransaction(){
                return $this->_pdo->beginTransaction();
            }
            public function commit(){
                 return $this->_pdo->commit();

            }
            public function rollBack(){
                 return $this->_pdo->rollBack();
            }
}

?>
```

IT is composed in `BaseApp Class`

```
    protected $db,
              $data,
              $table;


    public function __construct(){
        $this->db = DB::getInstance();
    }
        public function getProp($prop){

                return $this->$_prop;   


        }
         public function setProp($objVar,$val){
            $this->objVar = $val;

        }

        public function create($fields = array()){
if(!$this->db->insert($this->table, $fields) ){
    throw new Exception('There was a problem creating an account.');  

}

        }

        public function get($where = array()){
            $dbResult = $this->db->get($this->table, $where);
            if($dbResult->count()){
                $this->data = $dbResult->first();


                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        public function update($fields = array(),$id = null){
        if(!$this->db->update($this->table,$id,$fields)){
            throw new Exception('There was a problem Updating');
        }
        }


    public function delete($where = array()){
        $this->db->delete($this->table,$where);
                }
                public function data(){
                    return $this->data;
                }
    public function getTable(){
        return $this->table;
    }
    public function getLastInsertId(){
        return $this->db->getLastId();
    }
}




?>
```

which is extended by

```
   public function __construct(){

    parent::__construct();
     if($this->db){
        echo 'WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW';
     }

   }

    public function beginTransaction(){
        return $this->db->beginTransaction();
    }
    public function commit(){
        return $this->db->commit();
    }
    public function rollBack(){
        return $this->db->rollBack();
    } 
}

?>
```

Then

```
    protected $EqRqst_ID,
              $DateOfRequest,
              $rqstState,
              $RequestedPackage = array(),
              $state_ID,
              $table = 'EqRqst';

    public function __construct(RqstState $state){
        parent::__construct();

        $this->rqstState = $state;

    }
   public function create($args = array()){
     BaseTransactApp::create($args);
   // $this->EqRqst_ID = $this->getLastInsertId();
   // echo $this->EqRqst_ID;
   }
    public function getRqstID(){
     return $this->EqRqst_ID;
    }
    public abstract function makeRequest($requestArg = array(),$elRqst = array(),$rqstPakg = array());



}

?>
```

This trait contains the code that is Use by eqleaserequest .This code executes well without transactions but fails to do so with them

```
    public function makeRequest($requestArg = array(),$eqLsRqst = array(),$rqstPakg = array()){

        try{

        $this->beginTransaction();
        parent::create($requestArg);
        $this->EqRqst_ID = parent::getLastInsertId();
        $this->create($eqLsRqst);
        $this->_RequestPkg->create(multi_array_merge(array('EqRqst_ID'=> $this->EqRqst_ID),$rqstPakg));
     $this->commit();
            }catch(Exception $e){
                $this->rollBack();
                echo $e->getMessage().;
            }
        //$this->EqRqst_ID = $this->getRqstID();
    }
```

This code is the problem it runs when I comment out the Transaction code but doesn't with it. IT Executed by

This class is the one that uses the TraitRequest

```
    use traitRequest;

   //protected  $table = 'EqLeaseRequest';



    private $_Emp,
            $_Emp_ID,
            $_RequestPkg,
            $_Intended_Use,
            $_EqRqst,
            $_EqRqst_ID,
            $_Expected_Returndate;


     public $rqstID;

    public function __construct(RqstState $state,Employee $Emp,RequestPackage $RqstPkg){


        parent::__construct($state);
        $this->_Emp = $Emp;
        $this->_RequestPkg = $RqstPkg;



    }
   public function create($eqLsRqstArg = array()){
       $this->table = 'EqLeaseRequest';
       print_r(array_merge(array('EqRqst_ID'=> $this->EqRqst_ID),$eqLsRqstArg));
       BaseTransactApp::create(array_merge(array('EqRqst_ID'=>$this->EqRqst_ID),$eqLsRqstArg));
       //BaseTransactApp::create($eqLsRqstArg);



   }



    }


}


?>
```

Comment: What's your error? And, can you shorten your code?

Comment: The error is  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error

Comment: please try to paste your code more readable , this way people can be much more helpful and your question will be much more understandable.

Comment: Thanks for all those who tried, I am glad to say that I was able to solve the problem and  I have posted the solution.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to find the solution by changing the code in the Trait traitRequest.

The solution is as follows

trait traitRequest{
    public function makeRequest($requestArg = array(),$eqLsRqst = array(),$rqstPakg = array()){

```
    $this->beginTransaction();
    parent::create($requestArg);
     if(parent::count()){
         $this->EqRqst_ID = parent::getLastInsertId();
         $this->create($eqLsRqst);
         if($this->count()){
              foreach($rqstPakg as $pkg){
                  $this->_RequestPkg->create(array_merge(array('EqRqst_ID'=> $this->EqRqst_ID),$pkg));
                    if(!$this->_RequestPkg->count()){
                 $this->rollBack(); 
            }

              }
              $this->commit();


         }else{
             echo 'Second Rollback';
          $this->rollBack();
         }
     }else{


        echo 'First Rollback';
          $this->rollBack();
     }
}
```

}

?>